# How to create UDF in BigQuery? Routine name missing dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

The following is the definition of a working function I have in a postgres db:

```
create function my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric) returns numeric
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    _charge numeric;
BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0.00::numeric(19, 2);
    END IF;
    _charge := GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)::numeric(19, 2);
    RETURN (_charge + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00))::numeric(19, 2);
END;
$$;

alter function my_function(numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric) owner to my_location;
```

But when I try the following in BigQuery:

```
create function my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric) returns numeric
    language plpgsql
as
"""
DECLARE
    _charge numeric;
BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0.00::numeric(19, 2);
    END IF;
    _charge := GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)::numeric(19, 2);
    RETURN (_charge + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00))::numeric(19, 2);
END;
""";
```

I get the following error:

```
Routine name "my_function" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.
```

What is the command/syntax I am missing? I don't see a lot of documentation with concrete sql on how to correct for this.

**Update: So far I have the following BigQuery I think is on the right track but it still gives errors for floating point literal 0.00 and other incompatible syntaxes**

```
create procedure my_schema.my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric)
BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0.00::numeric(19, 2);
    END IF;
    _charge := GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)::numeric(19, 2);
    RETURN (_charge + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00))::numeric(19, 2);
END;
```

Comment: 1) just use `dataset.function_name` or `project.dataset.function_name` notion 2) if you want to use BQ scripting - you should rather use procedure - see [CREATE PROCEDURE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this right now. But can you clairify the differences between what I'm trying as a function and how it needs to be a procedure in detail? Will this simply not work as a function, is it more efficient as a proceure, etc.

Comment: scripting is not supported in BQ functions. so if your logic involves scripting - proc is your option. make sense? :o)

Comment: yes, it does! do you have any input on how my syntax needs to change to be the comparable bigquery version of this postgres though?

Comment: your question was specifically about `Routine name missing dataset`. I recommend you to try port your existing code into BQ proc and if you still have any issue  - post new/separate question and I/we will be more than happy to help! that is what we do here on SO :o)

Comment: Sure thing, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760748/proper-procedure-syntax-for-postgres-function-as-procedure-in-bigquery. If you want to post your first comment as an answer I'll mark that as the best solution and close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- just use dataset.function_name or project.dataset.function_name notion
- if you want to use BQ scripting - you should rather use procedure - see [CREATE PROCEDURE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure). Scripting is not supported in BQ functions. so if your logic involves scripting - proc is your option to go with

Answer (score -1):

**A sample for Parameterized User Defined Function is given below:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `Project_Name.DataSet_Name.User_Defined_Function_Name`(Field Data_Type) AS 
(
SELECT  COALESCE(Feild, 0) AS Filed2
);
```