# Proper procedure syntax for Postgres Function as Procedure in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, bigquery-udf

I have the following function in postgres:

```
create function my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric) returns numeric
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    _charge numeric;
BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0.00::numeric(19, 2);
    END IF;
    _charge := GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)::numeric(19, 2);
    RETURN (_charge + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00))::numeric(19, 2);
END;
$$;

alter function my_function(numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric) owner to my_location;
```

I'd like to convert this into BigQuery for the same functionality and so far I've tried:

```
create procedure my_schema.my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric)
BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0.00::numeric(19, 2);
    END IF;
    _charge := GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)::numeric(19, 2);
    RETURN (_charge + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00))::numeric(19, 2);
END;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Syntax error: Expected ";" but got floating point literal "0.00" at [4:16]
```

What is the proper command to produce the same postgres-style-function as a procedure successfully in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the procedure in BigQuery by replacing the return data type to `FLOAT64`. Try this script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mydataset.my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric)
  BEGIN
    IF qty = 0 THEN 
        SELECT 0.00 AS FLOAT64;
    END IF;
     SELECT (GREATEST(price * qty, min_charge)  + COALESCE(other_fee, 0.00)) AS FLOAT64;
  END;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to convert this into BigQuery for the same functionality

Consider below example

```
create temp function my_function(price numeric, qty numeric, min_charge numeric, other_fee numeric) 
returns numeric as (
  case when qty = 0 then 0
    else greatest(price * qty, min_charge) + coalesce(other_fee, 0)
  end
);
select my_function(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

if you want permanent function - just remove temp in `create temp function`

Comment: have you tried? did this work for you? if it is  - consider voting up - this motivates us to answer your next questions :o)